# Sublime Text and Hypens vs Underscores

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm running into an issue with hyphens in sublime text 3 and I was looking for some help.  I'd like them work the same way that underscores do.

With underscores, double clicking on word_one selects the whole thing while using the keyboard with ctrl-right hops to the underscore.

With hypens, double clicking on word-two selects the whole thing but using the keyboard with ctrl-right skips the entire word.  If I add the hyphen to the "word separators" then the behavior is switched (double clicking now just selects the word you click but ctrl-right works properly).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what _exactly_ you want to happen with ctrl+right and double-clicking for words with hyphens and underscores?

Comment: I'd just like hypenated words to work the same way words with underscores work.  It's also the same way camel case words work (doubling clicking on wordOne selects it all, but using ctrl-right would jump to the "O").

Comment: Apologies; I asked for specifics because my Windows 8.1 ST3 installation treats underscores differently than yours appears to. I think I get what you mean; "just like underscores" tripped me up, which is why I wanted something more like your camelCase example. What platform are you on? And is the underscore a part of your `word_separators`?

Comment: No worries at all.  I wasn't quite sure what you were looking for because I go through the behavior in my question so I'm glad the camel case example helped!  I'm on a Mac, using Sublime Text 3. Underscore is not a part of my word_separators. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove the hyphen from the list of characters that Sublime uses to define what a word is. This is stored in your preferences file. The default looks like this:

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?",
```

If you're feeling super-lazy, I've removed the hyphen for you here:

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"':,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?",
```

Of course, you should edit this in your User settings file.  You can open that file by selecting the menu "Sublime Text->Preferences->Settings - User".

Comment: Sorry, it's already not in the word separators. And as I say above, if I add it that doesn't fix it either.  I don't think the word separators is the solution, at least not by itself.