# Sublime Text 3: Use double underscore "__" as word separator

Tags: settings, sublimetext3

I am trying to use a double underscore "__" as word separator in Sublime Text 3. That means, I want the following to be selected by a double click (selection indicated by brackets):

- (bar_foo)
- (hello)__(world)

Is that possible? My first guess is "no", because nothing is specified in *Preferences.sublime-settings*, but maybe one of you guys knows a way to make this work?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I already had a look at some questions here at SO (e.g. [Removed hyphen from word_separators, ctrl+d no longer makes sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974288/removed-hyphen-from-word-separators-ctrld-no-longer-makes-sense/24001230#24001230) and [Sublime Text and Hypens vs Underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403806/sublime-text-and-hypens-vs-underscores)), but they don't answer this specific question.

Edit: In case you're wondering, I want this because I want to select variables like *bar_foo_counter* but I also want to use double underscores for my CSS modifier classes, like *bar__inner*.

Comment: This should be possible with a custom plugin, but not out of the box. I'll look into writing one if I have time.

Comment: That'd be awesome :)

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know Python, would you? It should be relatively straightforward - make a selection, check contents of selection for `__`, if present split selection and only select portion where cursor was. No big deal, I'm just not sure I'll have time to work on it now.

Comment: I know Python but I don't speak it, sorry :)

Comment: @MattDMo Have you accomplished this？

Comment: @jfxiao no I haven't, sorry.

Comment: Presumably things have changed since this question was asked because this now seems to work just fine out of the box in Sublime Text 3.